# Magento 2: I want to Install another setup of Magento in live site

Tags: magento2, theme, installation, server-setup, cpanel

I have a Magento store set up already working fine It is using `Venus Theme`,

Now I wanted to use `another theme`, When I installed and applied the theme, the `Homepage` is not working `properly`, `UI` is broken, nothing shows on `Homepage` etc.

I was not able to set the Site right after changing the theme.

Now I wanted to `install` another `setup` of `Magento` in my `Cpanel` with the `sample data` to show my management and eventually`customize` the site and move it to live.

for example: `www.example.com/test` here I want to install a new version of Magento,

Please help me if this possible or guide the ideal way of doing this. much appreciated your response.

Comment: What you want to fix first theme issue or new installation?

Comment: I want to set up a new installation without affecting existing working setup.

Comment: Ok so for new installation you can download Magento package and upload it on your server than can start installation.

Comment: @JBPakalapati you can create test folder setup new Magento to inside and configure.

Answer (score 1):

It's normal when applying a new custom theme to existing website.
Your first issue mostly relates to static content deploy and permission.

> for example: www.example.com/test here I want to install a new version
>   of Magento,

Does your hosting support subdomain? It's better to use subdomain.
Should not put a new install under a subfolder.
But but.. using the same server with the live site is a not good idea. We should have separate servers for testing environments.

Comment: Okay, understood.